# Why does the MATLAB XML DOM indexing not work?

Tags: xml, matlab, indexing

I have an `XML` file of the form

```xml
<ConfigFile>
   ...
   <ProgramSettings>
      ...
      <FlightConditions>
         <FlightCondition ID=1>
            <Mach>0.70</Mach>
            <Alitude>35000</Altitude>
         </FlightCondition>
         ...
         <FlightCondition ID=11>
            <Mach>0.78</Mach>
            <Altitude>35000</Altitude>
         </FlightCondition>
      </FlightCondtions>
   </ProgramSettings>
</ConfigFile>
```

from which I'm trying to read the 11 flight conditions in `MATLAB`.
My code so far looks like this:

```matlab
folder = 'path_to_folder';
config = xmlread(strjoin([folder, 'calculatePolar_conf.xml'],''));

flightConditionsNode = item(getElementsByTagName(config, 'FlightConditions'),0);
flightConditions = getElementsByTagName(flightConditionsNode, 'FlightCondition');

   for k=0:flightConditions.getLength-1
      flightCondition = item(flightConditions,k);
      removeChild(flightConditionsNode, flightCondition);
   end

xmlwrite(strjoin([folder,'output_config.xml'],''),config);
```

Up until now I'm simply trying to delete the 11 `FlightCondition` nodes, to replace them with a new, smaller list afterwards.

Unfortunately, the given code only deletes every second `FlightCondition` from the file, throwing an error after `k=5`. I have no idea why that is.

When I display the value of `flightConditions.getLength`, I get 11 as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:
`removeChild(flightConditionsNode, flightCondition);` also removes the deleted node from the list, the loop iterates over. Therefore, with each iteration the list size is changed,always moving the next element that should be deleted to index 0.

Consequently, the correct loop to delete all elements looks like this:

```
for k=0:flightConditions.getLength-1
    flightCondition = item(flightConditions,0);
    removeChild(flightConditionsNode, flightCondition);
end
```